# Viewing 3D model in a browser

Tags: plugins, browser, 3d, autocad-plugin

How can i see a 3d model in a web browser? Is there any existing plugin or something that can be used to visualise the 3d models generated by AutoCAD or something in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Make DWF and use [Freewheel](http://freewheel.autodesk.com/) to display it in a browser.